# Ambiguous columns error in pyspark while iteratively joining dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently writing a code to join(left) two dataframes multiple times iteratively based on a set of columns corresponding to the two dataframes on each iteration. For one iteration it is working fine but on second iteration I am getting ambiguous columns error.

This is the sample dataframe on which I am working

```
sample_data = [("Amit","","Gupta","36678","M",4000),
               ("Anita","Mathews","","40299","F",5000), 
               ("Ram","","Aggarwal","42124","M",5000),  
               ("Pooja","Anne","Goel","39298","F",5000),    
               ("Geeta","Banuwala","Brown","12345","F",-2)  
  ] 
sample_schema = StructType([
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True),
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True),
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)
])   
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = sample_data, schema = sample_schema) 

sample_data = [("Amit", "ABC","MTS","36678",10),
               ("Ani", "DEF","CS","40299",200), 
               ("Ram", "ABC","MTS","421",40),   
               ("Pooja", "DEF","CS","39298",50),    
               ("Geeta", "ABC","MTS","12345",-20)   

  ] 
sample_schema = StructType([
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True),
    StructField("Company",StringType(),True),
    StructField("position",StringType(),True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("points", IntegerType(), True)
])  
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data = sample_data, schema = sample_schema)
```

The code I used for this is

```
def joint_left_custom(df1, df2, cols_to_join, cols_df1_to_keep, cols_df2_to_keep):
    
    resultant_df = None
    df1_cols = df1.columns
    df2 = df2.withColumn("flag", lit(True))
    
    for i in range(len(cols_to_join)):
        joined_df = df1.join(df2, [(df1[col_1] == df2[col_2]) for col_1, col_2 in cols_to_join[i].items()], 'left')

        joined_df = joined_df.select(*[df1[column] if column in cols_df1_to_keep else df2[column] for column in cols_df1_to_keep + cols_df2_to_keep])

        df1 = (joined_df
               .filter("flag is NULL")
               .select(df1_cols)
              )
        
        resultant_df = (joined_df.filter(col("flag") == True) if i == 0 
                        else resultant_df.filter(col("flag") == True).union(resultant_df)
                       )
        
    return resultant_df

cols_to_join = [{"id": "id"}, {"firstname":"firstname"}]
cols_df1_to_keep = ["firstname", "middlename", "lastname", "id", "gender", "salary"]
cols_df2_to_keep = ["company", "position", "points"]
x = joint_left_custom(df1, df2, cols_to_join, cols_df1_to_keep, cols_df2_to_keep)
```

it works fine if I execute this code for single run but on second iteration for again joining the rest of the rows on column "firstname" which are not joined on basis of column "id" in first iteration it is throwing following error

> Column position#29518, company#29517, points#29520 are ambiguous. It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same. This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one. Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g. `df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id")`. You can also set spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false to disable this check.

Comment: are you trying to merge on id OR firstname match?

Comment: On first iteration I am trying to merge on "id" and then in second iteration I am merging on "firstname" if all rows of left dataframe are not merged in first iteration

Comment: I see.  hmm, it sounds like you are trying to join on id or on firstname if you are trying twice.  Could you try `df1.join(df2, on=(df1.id == df2.id) | (df1.firstname == df2.firstname), how='left')` and let me know if the result is what you are looking for or if not, how different?

Comment: Actually, I am writing this code to dynamically handle joins

Comment: Could you try the code and see the output is correct? I can help converting it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example how you can do `or` conditional join.

```
df1.join(df2, on=(df1.id == df2.id) | (df1.firstname == df2.firstname), how='left')
```

To make the condition dynamic, you can use `reduce` to chain the conditions.

```
from functools import reduce

def chain_join_cond(prev, value):
    (lcol, rcol) = list(value.items())[0]
    return prev | (df1[lcol] == df2[rcol])

# If your condition is OR, use False for initial condition.
# If your condition is AND, use True for initial condition(and use & to concatenate the conditions.)
cond = reduce(chain_join_cond, cols_to_join, F.lit(False))

# Use the cond for `on` option in join.
# df1.join(df2, on=cond, how='left')
```

Then to get a specific column set from df1 or df2 use list comprehensions to generate the `select` statement.

```
df = (df1.join(df2, on=cond, how='left')
      .select(*[df1[c] for c in cols_df1_to_keep], *[df2[c] for c in cols_df2_to_keep]))
```

If you have the `cols_to_join` as tuple instead of dict, you can slightly simplify the code.

```
cols_to_join = [("id", "id"), ("firstname", "firstname")]
cond = reduce(lambda p, v: p | (df1[v[0]] == df2[v[1]]) , cols_to_join, F.lit(False))
```